# In a SQL query, how do you avoid repeating the `GROUP BY` columns in the `SELECT` columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a SQL grouping query we often want to apply some complex formulas and return the grouped value amongst the return columns. e.g. in the following query the `EXTRACT`, `CASE` and `OTHER_...` seem to be pointlessly repeated after both the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` columns.

Boilerplate solution:

```
SELECT   
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) AS "month",
    CASE 
        WHEN price < 100 THEN 'low_price' 
        ELSE 'high_price' 
    END AS price_category,
    OTHER_COMPLEX_GROUPING_FUNCTION(price) AS foo,
    AVG(bar) AS avg_bar,
    AVG(baz) AS avg_baz,
    SUM(lorem) AS total_lorem,
    SUM(ipsum) AS total_ipsum
FROM 
    my_table
WHERE 
    date > '2023-01-01'
GROUP BY    
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date),
    CASE WHEN price < 100 THEN 'low_price' ELSE 'high_price' END,
    OTHER_COMPLEX_GROUPING_FUNCTION(price)
```

Lots of repetition in the return columns leads to more verbose, less readable code. It probably  also results in duplicating the computation effort (please confirm).

---

This got me thinking "Wouldn't it be great if we could define these columns in the `GROUP BY` on-the-fly?". Such as

My ideal solution:

```
SELECT "month"
       , price_category
       , foo
       , AVG(bar) AS avg_bar
       , AVG(baz) AS avg_baz
       , SUM(lorem) AS total_lorem
       , SUM(ipsum) AS total_ipsum        
FROM my_table
WHERE date > '2023-01-01'
GROUP BY    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) AS "month"
              , CASE WHEN price < 100 THEN 'low_price' ELSE 'high_price' END AS price_category
              , OTHER_COMPLEX_GROUPING_FUNCTION(price) AS foo
```

Do any SQL dialects offer some way to avoid this duplication *within* the `GROUP BY`? If not, why not?

(I am personally most interested to find a Postgres solution, but this question is generically applicable)

---

One solution is with a sub-query. I suspect that sub-queries like the following one can technically achieve the same outcomes, but they seem less readable and less idiomatic - especially if you had several other final return columns you wanted to include.

Existing solution:

```
  SELECT "month"
       , price_category
       , foo
       , AVG(price) AS avg_price
       , AVG(bar) AS avg_bar
       , AVG(baz) AS avg_baz
       , SUM(lorem) AS total_lorem
       , SUM(ipsum) AS total_ipsum
    FROM (SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM my_table) AS "month"
               , CASE WHEN price < 100 THEN 'low_price' ELSE 'high_price' END AS price_category
               , OTHER_COMPLEX_GROUPING_FUNCTION(price) AS foo
               , price
               , bar
               , baz
               , lorem
               , ipsum
            FROM my_table
            WHERE date > '2023-01-01'
          )
    GROUP BY "month", price_category, foo
```

Comment: The prefer the existing solution. Portable and correct!

Answer (score 3):

Use column *numbers*:

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) AS "month"
    , CASE WHEN price < 100 THEN 'low_price' ELSE 'high_price' END AS price_category
    , OTHER_COMPLEX_GROUPING_FUNCTION(price) AS foo
    , AVG(bar) AS avg_bar
    , AVG(baz) AS avg_baz
    , SUM(lorem) AS total_lorem
    , SUM(ipsum) AS total_ipsum
FROM my_table
WHERE date > '2023-01-01'
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: In PostgreSQL, you can also use result column aliases in the `GROUP BY` clause. That deviates from the standard, but is more readable.